# Extracting Get / Post events from server terminal using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write an application that acts as an event listener on a server. I'm currently deploying a test server with python `SimpleHTTPServer` and tunneling it out using `ngrok`, so I can have a public url in order to add a callback url to each contract. Below is a picture of the callback I am receiving from the `SimpleHTTPServer` terminal.

[image]

I also have a simple GUI using `tkinter` called `gui.py` shown below:
[image]

If the user clicks scan, the application should start scanning the server for any events and process the response if found.

I tried tried to create a `client.py` and using socket to connect to the server and I was able to successfully connect with the following code below.

```
import socket

class Client:

    def __init__(self):

        # Assign ip & port number to instance variable
        self.HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        self.PORT = 4040

        # Set up our main socket
        self.main_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self):

        # Try and connect the socket to the server
        try:

            # Binding out host and ip to the socket
            self.main_socket.connect((self.HOST, self.PORT))

            return 'Server Connected...'

        # Print any error message for not being able to connect
        except Exception as e:

            return str(e)

    def disconnect(self):

        # Try and disconnect the socket from the server
        try:

            # Call the disconnect function to disconnect the socket
            self.main_socket.close()

            return 'Server Disconnected...'

        # Print any error message from not being able to connect
        except Exception as e:
            return 'Cannot disconnect from the server: ' + e
```

## Question:

Is there anyway for me to capture the event from the SimpleHTTPServer terminal (Picture 1) and store them into variables?

I read up on using subprocesses, but not sure if that would apply in this case.

Comment: Not exactly sure all you're trying to accomplish, but I think you should take a look at the requests package and see if it will make the job easier for you. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @Dave What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to extract the event logs (picture 1) and store them into variables. Our API has a field called callbackurl, which will ping the server that the url is hosted on with event changes. I am familiar with the request library and know how to perform the HTTP Get / Post request, but the problem is I need to extract the documentID, eventType, and status in order to make those calls. My attempt was to create a client to connect to the same ip and port as the SimpleHTTPServer to see if I can somehow redirect the events into my program.

Comment: how about logging the HTTPServer to a file rather than just returning to the terminal, and then grabbing the updates out of that file. You could monitor the file for changes, and grab the last line(s) using tail, grep, and/or other tools (assuming linux).

You could then respond to each line as you desired using the file as a queue.

Comment: That could definitely be a possible solution. Let me look into seeing if there's a way to storing the events into a log. Thanks for the insight. I appreciate it.